# C++, Почему сортировка срабатывает только 1 раз в цикле?

Tags: c++

Я пытаюсь запустить сортировку слиянием 10 раз, первая итерация цикла проходит успешно, а последующая приводит к терминированию процесса `"Process terminated with status -1073741510 (0 minute(s), 10 second(s))"`

Я допускаю, что есть какая-то проблема с передачей указателя `int *b = getRandom(n);` в функцию сортировки, т.к. если передавать обычный массив, например `int b[5] = {5,4,3,2,1};`, то все окей, но я не понимаю в чем моя ошибка.

Вот код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#define print(x) cout<<x;
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

void merge(int arr[], int l, int m, int r)
{
    int i, j, k;
    int n1 = m - l + 1;
    int n2 = r - m;

    int L[n1], R[n2];

    for (i = 0; i < n1; i++)
        L[i] = arr[l + i];
    for (j = 0; j < n2; j++)
        R[j] = arr[m + 1+ j];

    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    k = l;
    while (i < n1 && j < n2)
    {
        if (L[i] <= R[j])
        {
            arr[k] = L[i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            arr[k] = R[j];
            j++;
        }
        k++;
    }

    while (i < n1)
    {
        arr[k] = L[i];
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    while (j < n2)
    {
        arr[k] = R[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}

void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r)
{
    if (l < r)
    {
        int m = l+(r-l)/2;

        mergeSort(arr, l, m);
        mergeSort(arr, m+1, r);

        merge(arr, l, m, r);
    }
}

int* getRandom(int count) {

    int* randomDigits = new int[count];

    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
    randomDigits[i] = rand();
    }

   return randomDigits;
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");

    int n = 40906;
    unsigned int start_time;
    unsigned int end_time;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
        cout << "Итерация " << i << endl;
        start_time = clock();
        int *b = getRandom(n);
        mergeSort(b, 0, n);
        end_time = clock() - start_time;
        cout << "Время выполнения сортировки алгоритмом Слиянием: " << end_time << " мс." << endl;
        }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `int L[n1], R[n2];` кто вас так писать всех учил... VLA это не стандартная вещь и писать так не стоит.

Comment: Кстати, вот это - `srand(time(NULL));` - в результате приводит к заполнению массива в разных итерациях одними и теми же данными с высочайшей вероятностью... Кстати, а как оно у вас вообще скомпилировалось - код, который не принадлежит ни одной функции?...

Comment: и память течёт ещё)

Comment: https://ideone.com/eICoRU так что говорите не работает у вас?

Comment: В безымянном(глобальном) пространстве  имен  выполняете какие то расчеты?...

Comment: Где в вашем коде функция `merge`??? Что за странный код болтается "в чистом поле" в самом начале?  И `int L[n1], R[n2];` - в С++ такое не допускается.

Comment: @pavel, чисто ради спортивного интереса, что вы имеет ввиду? Что не стоит "так" писать?)

Comment: @entithat через VLA. или нормальный массив через new или вообще создать буфер того же размера и не парится с выделением памяти.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Классическая ошибка "на один".

Изначально вы формируете массив `b` размера `n`. Однако в функцию сортировки `mergeSort` вы передаете индексы `l = 0` и `r = n`. Это уже неправильно. Ваша функция `mergeSort` написана так, что параметры `l` и `r` должны быть корректными индексами элементов массива. Индекс `r = n` не является корректным индексом элемента массива.

В конечном итоге эта ошибка приводит к тому, что функция `merge` полагает, что исходный массив имел размер `n + 1` (`n1 + n2` у вас получается равно `n + 1`). Она выполняет запись за пределы массива, что приводит к неопределенному поведению в самом конце первой итерации (или, скорее всего, даже раньше).

Comment: а в каком месте предполагается, что r - индекс массива. Я просто привык писать, что r указывает на конец массива а не на последний элемент. Здесь вроде бы тоже нет выхода. Ну или я его не заметил)

Comment: @pavel: Во многих. Например, рекурсивные вызовы `mergeSort`. Если бы речь шла о полуоткрытых интервалах `[l, r)`, то рекурсивные вызовы выглядели бы как `mergeSort(arr, l, m);  mergeSort(arr, m, r);`, а в коде во втором вызове стоит `m + 1`, что сразу означает, что подразумеваются закрытые интервалы `[l, r]`. Ну и, еще раз, ошибка "на один" в `merge`.